# Receive value from retrofit async query

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I need to return List-object from retrofit-response in my findUser() method. What is the right way to do this? 
One of the possible way it's declare static-variable in class and in onResponse() method set some value to it, but i think it is wrong way.

```
public static List<UserItem> findUser(){
        Call<UserAnswer> call = service.findUser();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserAnswer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserAnswer> call, Response<UserAnswer> response) {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserAnswer> call, Throwable t) {}

        });
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: you can't get exactly this. async means the call is asynchronous, you can't simply wait for it to complete before continuing your process. Instead, use the callback to do whatever you have to do with the result

Comment: Got it, for creating callback methods in activity i need to declare Interface and activity should to implement this interface. And i need to call this methods from class, which contain retrofit query-methods, so i need to some access mechanism to activity object, i can do this by declare method in my retrofit class which receives activity-reference, but it's dangerous by possible memory leak, what is right way to get access to activity's callback method?

Comment: 2 main options: use `WeakReference` to have non-blocking references to the Activity, or unregister your listener in the `onPause` of your activity